# Working a PyQGIS Script in cmd, outside of the QGIS python console

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3, command-line

I have a perfectly fine working script that runs within the QGIS Python Console and I would like to run the script outside of the software, preferably in cmd as a .bat, so then I can use task scheduler to run the task every minute. I am using QGIS downloaded with OSGEO4W64. My .bat looks like this and runs, until it encounters a variable within QGIS e.g. `QGSRasterLayer` or `QgsPrintLayout`:

```
ECHO OFF
cd C:\Path\to\.py Script
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\python.exe .\Full_Script.py
PAUSE

NameError: name 'QgsRasterLayer' is not defined
```

I know I have to do `from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer` but every time I try to use this piece of code, it says that `'qgis' is not defined`. I have looked into many forums on this site and have looked mainly into path and `PYTHONPATH` environment variables. My path looks like this:

```
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python37
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python37\lib
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python37\Scripts
C:\OSGeo4W\bin\qgis-bin.exe
```

And my `PYTHONPATH` looks like this:

```
c:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python
```

I have also tried using `sys.path.append` but I have had no luck so far. Can anyone help me out so I can sort out this problem and finally get my script working outside of QGIS, as I am struggling to find a way how to resolve this issue? Have I inputted the paths wrong or do I need to do something else, in order so that I can import `qgis.core` and be able to use all the elements (`QgsRasterLayer` etc) in my script, outside of QGIS.

EDIT: I currently have it working now but it comes up with the error: NoneType object has no attribute 'RasterLayer'

Comment: Is there any reason you use pure cmd instead of  OSGeo Shell (which is also cmd)?

Comment: Hi Kadir, no reason in particular. I just thought that the easiest way would be through cmd. If it easier, I can use OSGeo Shell if you could help me getting it working through that? Thanks

Comment: I've already tried. I get the same error in OSGeo Shell.

Comment: Ah that is annoying... I have been trying to get it working for a while but unfortunately I have not got anywhere with it yet...

Comment: please do not post pictures of your code or environment variables - it is impossible for some users to read (and just hard for the rest of us).

Comment: I have removed the pictures and instead put text/code, could you un delete the post now please? @IanTurton

Comment: @xunilk So by installing the GDAL binaries, would I then be able to import qgis on the OSGEO4W64 Power shell?

Comment: If you install them with success you can also use cmd.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out now

Comment: @xunilk I have MSC v.1914 but when I go to download the GISInternals, there is no -1914 version. I am assuming it would be the -1911 version with GDAL 2.4.4? Which one should I download?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118119/discussion-between-liamhems-and-xunilk).

Comment: I have seemed to get it working somehow. However, when I run the script, I get the error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'addRasterLayer' on one of my lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run a pyqgis script - my_pyqgis_script.py in the example below - from outside, for example from a bat file, you should use the following syntax within your bat file:

```
"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\bin\python-qgis.bat" my_pyqgis_script.py
```

you have to adjust the path to python-qgis.bat, in your case something like C:\OSGeo4W\qgis\bin just look for the python-qgis.bat file. In your python script you have to load all libraries like you described above (from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer and so on).
The python-qgis.bat will set all relevant path information and finally call you script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Within the script, I have added all the libraries e.g. from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QColor etc. However, when I go to the .bat file, I double click it and the command window comes up but then nothing happens after that. When I try to run the actual script, the message "Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "" comes up. Any ideas?

Comment: Since I don't know your PyQGIS script it is difficult to say what is happening. It sounds that you are trying to use GUI elements? Normally if you want to start a QGIS Process from outside, let's say to print a layout or make some processing, you woulnd't use iface for that - with the program line: app = QgsApplication([], false). On the other side, there can be other programs on your programm using QT, which makes it more difficult, you can check with cmd and type echo %QT_PLUGIN_PATH%. This should be empty, if not delete it and try again.

Comment: Hi, I have managed to find and locate the Qt platform plugin using os.environ[QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH] and os.environ[PATH] but now it comes up with the error - NoneType object has no attribute 'RasterLayer'. I am guessing it is because I am using iface.addRasterLayer or iface.addVectorLayer. What would be the best way to add these in without using iface?

Comment: If you want to do something with the vectorlayer or rasterlayer in background there is no need to add it to a mapcanvas. for example: layer = QgsVectorLayer('D:/buildings_a.shp',u'OSM Gebäude Freiburg', 'ogr') will load a vectorlayer into the variable layer. From that point you can do anything with layer like reproject, export, add features and so on, no need to add it...

Comment: Thanks @eurojam for your answer. The simplest solution.